# Parcelable: Double Array , Calendar and Bitmap

Tags: java, arrays, calendar, double, drawable

I have a customer object class that I need to pass around from oneactivity to another.
Im using parcelable to help me do this but i have encountered some problems

## 1)Double Array variable# (Main Problem now)

I can `writeDoubleArray` but i cant `readDoubleArray`

The line `in.readDoubleArray();` is underlined in red and says :

> "The method `readDoubleArray(double[])` in the type Parcel is not applicable for the arguments ()"

## 2) Calendar Variable

I dont know what function to use to write the calendar so i just tried `writeValue`
I have not tested if it works properly. I need advice on this

## 3) Drawable Variable

I have a drawable attribute in my object and I have searched for a solution and I used it but the current one says it is depreciated. So im also not sure if it will work. I also need advice on this

#### I hope you can help me. Thanks!

---

My Codes:

---

```
          //My attributes
public class Event {

    public int eventID;
    public String eventName;
    public String eventDesc;
    public String category;
    public String vendor;
    public String venue;
    public Calendar startDateTime;
    public Calendar endDateTime;
    public Drawable eventImage;
    public double[] price;
    public double lat;
    public double lng;


           ....
           //Other constructors here
           ....
   
     public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
                    dest.writeInt(eventID);
                    dest.writeString(eventName);
                    dest.writeString(eventDesc);
                    dest.writeString(category);
                    dest.writeString(vendor);
                    dest.writeString(venue);
                    dest.writeValue(startDateTime);
                    dest.writeValue(endDateTime);
                    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) ((BitmapDrawable) eventImage).getBitmap();
                    dest.writeParcelable(bitmap,flags);
                    dest.writeDoubleArray(price);
                    dest.writeDouble(lat);
                    dest.writeDouble(lng);
                }
                
    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) { 
                     
                    eventID = in.readInt();
                    eventName = in.readString();
                    eventDesc = in.readString();
                    category = in.readString();
                    vendor = in.readString();
                    venue = in.readString();
                    startDateTime = (Calendar) in.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader());
                    endDateTime = (Calendar) in.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader());
                    Bitmap bitmap= (Bitmap)in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
                    eventImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                    price = in.readDoubleArray();
                    lat = in.readDouble();
                    lng = in.readDouble();
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to read a double array with a method, that requires a parameter. When using `readDoubleArray(double[])` you need to create the array (of a sufficient length) before calling the method passing in that array as a parameter.

When you don't want to create the array yourself use `in.createDoubleArray()` instead of `in.readDoubleArray(double[])`.

What comes to the Calendar-object, you can use the `Parcel.writeSerializable(Serializable)`-method, since the Calendar class implements the Serializable interface.

Comment: Thanks! As for the calendar , when I do it in the readFromParcel , am i right to do this? startDateTime = (Calendar) in.readSerializable();

Answer (score 1):

for read double array and Calendar

```
private double[] mDoubleArray;
private Calendar mCalendar;

private void readFromParcel(Parcel source) {
mDoubleArray= new double[source.readDouble()];
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
instance.setTimeInMillis(source.readLong());
mGroupKey = instance;
}

    @Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
dest.writeDoubleArray(mDoubleArray == null || mDoubleArray.length == 0 ? new double[] {} : mDoubleArray);  
dest.writeLong(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());

}
```